# How to get all tweets with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, twitter, webdriver

I want to get all tweets written all the time from an user. I writted a simple python script for that but the problem is when the browser opens page and gets tweets from page source code it gives only tweets from dead page. Dead page means we can't move in it. It shows only requested url. Twitter users know that the pages are dynamic. So the page is refreshed as it goes down. What I want is that the Selenium takes the page down by itself and takes the tweets to the end.

this is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver_path = "C:\\Users\\Muhammd\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe"

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= driver_path)
browser.get("https://twitter.com/ErhanErkut")
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
tweets = [p.text for p in soup.findAll('p', class_ = 'tweet-text')]
for i in tweets:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Use Twitter API, its very easy to get tweets using the API and python. More reliable and accurate tweet and its data.

Comment: https://www.alexkras.com/how-to-get-user-feed-with-twitter-api-and-python/
and https://stackabuse.com/accessing-the-twitter-api-with-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend twitter API instead (Notice the **screen_name** and **count**):

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='your-twitter app consumer key',
  consumer_secret='your secret',
  access_token_key='XXXX',
  access_token_secret='XXXXXX')

#print(api.VerifyCredentials())

tweets = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name="ErhanErkut", count=20)

print(tweets)
```

To run the above program, first install:

```
pip install python-twitter
```

And after this create a twitter `app` on `https://developer.twitter.com/`.
On the twitter app you can see the consumer keys and you can generate access tokens.

[Twitter Developer API reference](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index.html)

You can download big data using Twitter API.

Comment: tweets = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name="ErhanErkut", count=20) 

in this line: For count, Is the number of last tweets written?

Comment: yes latest one, see the time stamp when you print the tweets, it should be something like `Created=Wed Apr 17 16:04:11 +0000 2019`. I run the above code and got the tweets where I can see the `Created` date-time field.